# Floating footer bar - hiding using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a website using Bootstrap and I want to have a floating footer bar for choosing a language, Q&As etc.

But I would like to have a 'hide' button there.

It looks like this:

```html
    <div id="footer" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div id="innerFooter" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <a class="btn btn-default " data-toggle="collapse" href="#footer" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="footer">
                       Hide
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                
                ...some buttons..
                
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have two problems with it:

1. When I hide the bar and I go to another page, that bar pops up
   again.
2. When I click the hide button the first attempt doesn't do
   anything, but when I click for the second time, the bar hides.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**For the first problem:**

You have to store the state of the navbar visibility... 
If you don't code it, how the browser could know if it should show or not the navbar... ?

**For the second problem**

You want to collapse but there is no initial state.

You should had `collapse in` classes to your navbar

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/p1xNGxePan

**HTML** :

```
<div id="footer" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom collapse in">
    <div id="innerFooter" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" href="#footer" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="footer">
                   Hide
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">

            ...some buttons..

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```